# The match in mapbox expression is an exact match,how to use fuzzy match in the expression

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I use this method,but the result is exact match,can not fuzzy match

```
map.setPaintProperty('building_layeres', 'fill-extrusion-color', [
      'case',
      ['==', ['get', 'NAME'], '腾讯大厦'],
      'red',
      ['==', ['get', 'NAME'], '彩讯科技大厦'],
      'red',
      '#aaa',])
```

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox-GL only supports a very small range of string manipulation operators, which don't include regular expressions or other forms of wildcard.

You can see them here: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-string